# Сколько "экземпляров" .h  файла остается после построения проекта?

Tags: include, c++, visual-studio

После построения проекта остается один "экземпляр" .h файла или столько, сколько раз его подключали? Если второе, то спасает ли от этой лишней траты памяти `include guard`?

Под `include guard` я понимаю:

```
# pragma once
```

или

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H
// код
#endif
```

Comment: - `Header`-файлы без `include guards` никому не нужны.

- Сам по себе вопрос про *"экзэмпляры"* хэдеров говорит о том, что вы недостаточно разбираетесь в этапах работы компилятора и линковщика. То есть, грубо говоря, если разбираться в них, то такой вопрос просто не возникнет :)

Comment: А можно по конкретнее? У меня сейчас нет времени изучать этапы компиляции.

Comment: Этапы компиляции надо знать и понимать очень хорошо. Это несложно и изучение занимает немного. Получаса вполне достаточно, но без этого серьезное изучение и использование С++ просто невозможны.

Comment: Чтобы хорошо понимать, нужно найти хорошее объяснение. Поиск выдал только 2 ссылки, но и то там информации почти нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Include guard'ы нужны не для экономии памяти, а для предотвращения ошибок, могущих возникнуть при повторном включении одного и того же хедера в файл модуля.
2. Может сохраниться не сам хедер (текст которого  просто включается препроцессором в текст модуля), а то, что в нем содержится. Если в нем кроме объявлений функций содержатся еще разные константы, определения функций (что не хорошо, но встречается) или шаблоны, то тогда они компилируются отдельно для каждого объектного файла и далее собираются. Правда, некоторые линковщики могут находить такие повторы и элиминировать их.

Comment: Ну не может же быть, что разработчики компиляторов не решили проблему дублирования кода.

Comment: Я же говорю, при определенных условиях эта проблема решается, но на уровне линковщика.

Comment: @mikillskeg некоторые компиляторы хранят оттранслированные (правда не знаю в какую форму) заголовки. Для ускорения перетрансляции. Правда к вопросу @chevchelios это перпендикулярно, поскольку хедеры в промежуточном формате не дублируются.

Comment: @alexlz, Вы имеете в виду прекомилированные заголовки?

Comment: @mikillskeg Ага. Хотя к вопросу они отношения не имеют. Так, попытка сократить время повторной компиляции сотен тысяч строк...

Comment: Я намеренно в это не стал лезть, взял самый простой вариант, о котором собственно и шла речь.

Answer (score 1):

[[@chevchelios](/users/8262/chevchelios)](/users/8262/chevchelios), первый этап C/C++ компиляции это работа препроцессора.

Он читает заданный файл с программой, исполняет директивы, начинающиеся с символа `#` (`#define`, `#include` и т.д.) и делает *текстовые* макроподстановки (заменяет (грубо говоря) текст в программе на текст, определенный в директивах `#define`)

Т.е. препроцессор изменяет *ТЕКСТ* программы, особо не вникая в его смысл. Директива `#include` говорит о том, что вместо строки с ней надо вставить строки указанного файла (рекурсивно).

Если вы выполните gcc -E prog.c или g++ -E prog.cpp то увидите, как изменился текст Вашей программы. Он помещается во временный файл (или напрямую (по пайпу) передается компилятору). Именно этот текст обрабатывается компилятором, который производит *объектный модуль*.

По поводу разработчиков и решения проблемы дублирования. Она успешно решена. "Программисту" сообщают об его ошибках.

Comment: Первый этап я понимаю) А вот когда все эти .cpp файлы после преобразования в объектный модуль начнут объединяться в один файл, то тут я не знаю, что будет делать компилятор с дублированием. Раз вы говорите, что дублирования нет, то буду надеяться, что это так.

Comment: С дублированием чего именно? В .h файлах не содержится ничего, что создаёт имена в объектных файлах: тел функций, переменных, объектов классов и т.д. А если они по какому-то недоразумению туда попадут, то линковщик не соберёт программу, с диагностикой типа "дублирование имени xxx в модуле zzz".

Comment: С дублированием того, что компилятор разрешает дублировать, а именно прототипы функций, объявление классов/структур(тут я не уверен), объяв. глобальных объектов(extern int foo;) и может еще что-нибудь. Во всяких библиотечных .h файлов очень много такого "мусора".

Comment: Объявлений одной и той же функции может быть хоть тыща четыреста двадцать три в одном месте, компилятору на это глубоко чихать. Всё это (прототипы, шаблоны и пр) не создаёт объектов, и вообще, к линковке никакого отношения не имеет.  Для ускорения понимания этого факта попробуйте ответить на простой вопрос: зачем вообще нужны прототипы функций?

Comment: @chevchelios, лучший способ понять - это спланировать, а потом провести (**самому**) серию экспериментов. 

Вот когда у Вас в руках будут конкретные данные, которые Вы не понимаете, как интерпретировать, тогда спрашивайте.

Это я не от лени или злобы, а для Вашей пользы. Понимание будет на другом уровне.

Comment: Прототипы функции получается нужны только при построении объектного кода для каждого файла. klopp, вы хотите сказать, что на этом этапе компилятор удаляет все это не нужное? И тогда на вход компоновщику приходит уже построенный машинный код, а в нем уже нет никаких прототипов и объявлений.
Тогда все понятно.
avp
Вроде бы я все понял.

Comment: Вот представьте, матюгальник на вокзале говорит: "поезд номер 10 приходит к 5 платформе". И так 20 раз подряд. Появится от этого двадцать поездов? Не, придёт только один. Вот так и здесь. Компилятору не нужо ничего удалять, так как объявления влияют только на процесс построения объектов, но сами по себе ничего не создают.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.